# Angular Bootstrap: Navbar doesn't expand

Tags: html, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have an Angular project with Bootstrap for styling. I want to make a menu bar with a dropdown icon when the screen is too small to show al the menu items. When the screen is large, all the menu items are shown and when the screen is small the expand icon is shown, but the menu does not expand when clicking on the icon.

I have added bootstrap to my Angular project by doing the following: `ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

My html code looks like this (It was copied from the Bootstrap website):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This are the dependencies in the `package.json` file:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^14.0.0-beta.40",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0-alpha1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

I did the bootstrap.css import in the `styles.css` file like this

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Did I forget some imports or did I do something else wrong?

Comment: You need to use the actual component: [`<ul ngbNav>`](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/overview). That's the only way to get the javascript working. However, I see that they only implemented the `nav`s, and not the navbar. If you'd insist, you may want to take a look at [this navbar](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/navbar), [implemented here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/app.component.html#L1), [demonstrated here](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using ng-bootstrap ngbCollapse directive to handle collapse.

Look at this link, You will find complete example ([Responsive Navbar](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples)) of menu with collapse and expand.